# Angular 2/4 : How to load css file from Assets

Tags: html, css, angular, assets

In my .angular-cli.json, I define this :

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/assets/css/main.css",
  "styles.css"
],
```

And in my assets folder I have (assets/css/*.css) .. 
But when i run my app, CSS doesn't loaded .. How can I resolve it please ?
You can check jpeg file in attachment

[image]

Comment: I want to load it in my index.html and any component

Comment: Did you stop and rerun `ng serve` after updating your styles?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got same error once I have started Angular 4 project

What I have done is

In my assets there is no css

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.png"
      ],
```

And in style

```
"styles": [
        "../src/assets/css/main.css",
]
```

And then please do **ng serve** again

Hope this helps

Comment: I have just put "../" and its resolved my problem I have also added "../" in "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" as well

Comment: Thx for your help, I tried : ` "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],`  and ` "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../src/assets/css/main.css"
        ],` but Not Working

Comment: oh got.. ..hmmm can you please try with "./src/assets/css/main.css"?

Comment: Or may be with "/src/assets/css/main.css" it might work

Comment: And ya you need to do ng serve again, only then it will reflact

Comment: when ever you do change with  angular-cli.json you have to run command ng serve again

Comment: Ah ok .. it's the funny things .. I have not re-run my server ... I do it .. Thxxx

Comment: Yes after done changes in angular-cli.json or angular.json we have to re run it again

Answer (score 4):

Ran also into this issue, but I did it differently. I did not modify the `angular.json`. I imported the url in `styles.css` with `@import url("./app/custom-styles/custom-bootstrap.css");`. This way you don't need to restart for detection change. And you keep `styles.css` clean for your general styling stuff.

Don't know if it is the best way, but for me it helped a lot to keep it clean.

Answer (score 3):

always use double dots to go back. a single "../" use to go one directory back.
Now check where is your assets folder from your destination folder.
for me `../../assets/css/spinner.css` helped

Answer (score 2):

Go to assets folder then create new 'CSS folder & a styles.css file. Open 'angular.json' file give the path in "styles" section.